MSSQL self alias config
We had a server running a default single MSSQL as a named instance (named MyDB)
We had to rebuild the server, has the same dns name
They installed MSSQL on it and restored the old database to it
But when they installed MSSQL, they did so with the default instance name
So instead of Server1\MyDB its now Server1\MSSQLSERVER, and a lot of our old stuff broke
I'd like to add an alias in Server1's Sql Server Configuration Manager that will point the name MyDB at the MSSQLSERVER default instance.  I'm having trouble getting that to work, maybe becuase it's using the same port or I haven't config'd it correctly.
What settings should I use in create alias to get my setup to recognize the old instance name and just redirect it to the new instance.


First of all alias is added to client and not to the server. You should do it via
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cliconfg.exe

and this tool just create an registry entry in
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client\ConnectTo

or
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client\ConnectTo 

You can propagate those registry entries via group policy

So there’s no way to alias an instance name at the server? Cause I have non windows machines, even external vendors using Linux ssh bastion hosts to connect via java…

not in your configuration: from named instance to default one.

if it hurts really bad you can uninstall default instance and install named instance. If you save master, model, msdb database files (mdf and ldf) you don't have to restore or reconfigure anything. Check this link for steps https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/downgrading-sql-server-editions/ . You can configure named instance to accept connection without instance name if using default port 1433.
